# Ajax запрос ждет ответа от php

Tags: php, ajax

Использую аякс запрос, и хочу чтобы отправить запрос, и не ждать пока обработается пхп скрипт.

Но получается так, что я отправляю аякс запрос, и не могу перейти на любую другую страницу сайта, пока не обработается php скрипт.

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data
});

// php пока не посчитает не отдаст результат
<?php

$a = 0;
while($a < 100000000){
    $a++;
}

return;
```

Как быть в такой ситуации, и что делать для решения вопроса?

Comment: да это ж просто - используйте 2 ajax запроса один запрашивает url, дргуой файл $a = 0;
while($a < 100000000){
    $a++;
}

Comment: Поставьте timeout:1000. Или нужно что бы ответ пришел?

Comment: @G.Denis а чем таймаут поможет? Только через секунду выполнится.

Comment: @Mcile попробую так, интересный варик

Comment: @user190134 timeout это время после которого браузер перестает ждать ответа от сервера.

Comment: Вряд ли поможет. У меня на сайте 2 блока на страницы грузятся через ajax. Причем первый довольно долго. В итоге, пока первый не загрузится, второй блок не появляется

Comment: Я не правильно понял суть вопроса.

Comment: @ArchDemon у меня просто по SMTP письма шлет, и время на коннект к серверу занимает около 2х секунд, это очень долго. Решение нужно найти..

Comment: @Mcile не получилось, все равно ожидает ответа от того аякса.

Comment: @user190134 Вы все правильно сделали! Вам лишь осталось запустить ява скрипты асинхронно.  async

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы долго выполняющийся PHP скрипт (отправка почты) не "подвешивал" клиента, можно реализовать такую "асинхронную" технику: ваш PHP-скрипт send_mail_async.php инициирует запуск другого PHP-скрипта send_mail.php (который непосредственно занимается отправкой) и, не дожидаясь его окончания, возвращает результат.

```
  $url = 'send_mail.php?blah-blah=123&...';
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 50);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  echo "In a few minutes you will get an email. Check Spam folder ;)";
  exit;
```

Пишу "асинхронную" в кавычках, т.к. для реальной асинхронности не хватает обработки результатов скрипта по окончании выполнения. Но для маленьго ненагруженного проекта сгодится.

**UPDATE**

Если нужна проверка результатов отправки, можно формировать уникальный идентификатор сеанса отправки и периодически с клиента посылать запрос с проверкой результата отправки, используя этот идентификатор. Соответственно, скрипт отправки должен сохранять результат в табличку: in progress, fail, success...

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос, бок был у меня, вот в чем:

При аякс запросе, пыталась стартовать сессия поверх существующей, и оно вот так вот интересно отражало.

Решил следующим кодом

```
if( $_SESSION === NULL )
    session_start();
```

И все окей. Всем спасибо